Why aren't my tables listed by .table command?
I'm trying to make an SQLite database connection through Flask-sqlalchemy. I opened a command prompt where dbconnect.py is saved containing from dbconnect import app, db,Connect and db.create_all(). Then I opened sqlite3.exe (same location as the Python file) and did db.connect and .tables.
I was expecting Connect table to be listed but nothing came up. I can see the data in Visual Studio Code though. Where am I going wrong?
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.connect'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Connect(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20),nullable = False)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    entry = Connect(name = "Apple")
    db.session.add(entry)
    db.session.commit()
    dbdata = Connect.query.all()
    print(dbdata[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)


Are you sure that yuo are looking in the right place?

hint: search your drive for all db.connect files, most probably you just create a new db.connect  db with your sqlite3.exe command and do not open the existing one you wanted

Does this answer your question? db.create_all() doesn't create a database in a desired directory

@jhole
I didn't understand that in the right way. sorry. Can you help me a lil bit more, please?

[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Apple'}] This is the data i'm getting from the database while printing in the terminal. It does mean that there's a table, right? The code is also fine it seems. If I do select * from table name in sqlite3, it says no table exists with that table name.

Do you use the .mode column command? Command-Line doc
On windows double click sqlite3.exe opens the command line shell
than in the shell use your dot commands, like:
sqlite> .open c:\your_path\databasename.db # connect your existing database
sqlite> .tables # will show you the existing tables list.
sqlite> .mode column # set the table format for output
sqlite> select * from your_tablename;


I understood. thank you very much! :) @Hermann
